# How can I Transfer Google Chrome's Data and Settings to another Google Account?

Tags: google-chrome, user-profiles, data-transfer

I use Google Chrome and I have 100s of bookmarks, history, search preferences, search engines, extensions, and apps installed.

I want to have a new Google account, and I need to move everything from my current account to the new one.

I did sign in to another Chrome and transferred my bookmarks using the Export/Import option. How can I transfer all the Google Chrome data, saved usernames and passwords, and everything else to the new account?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Copy the user data (find it at ~/.config/google-chrome on Linux) then make a new user profile from the settings and delete the other one. Copy back the data and wait for it to sync.

Comment: I opened Appdata in Windows, and navigated to C:\Users\Thedijje\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data and found two folder named profile1 and default. I opened it and found that this all contain data from both user,i think copying data from Default to Profile1 should move data from one to another account after sync? isn't it?

Comment: Hang on a minute, you could do it a much easier way. (Sorry...) You can delete the other profile. Goto the menu and click "Signed in as thedijje@gmail.com" then click "disconnect", click "sign in" and click "sign in with a different account" if it doesn't let you change the username. Then sign in with the new account... done!

Answer (score 26):

[EDIT] According to Aminah Nuraini (in comments) the following is no longer the case.

I'm just going to post this here for greater visibility (as I found it very useful) for future people who come across it, credit goes to `user234593`:

Go to the menu and at the top under signed in as `youremail@gmail.com` click `disconnect` then click `sign in` and sign in as a different account.

When you click `disconnect` it warns you that all your data will stay on the computer (which is exactly what you want) and when you sign in with the new account the things get synced to that account

Comment: Outdated. Now they make sure all of the data got cleared when you do so

Comment: I just pressed "turn off" in the sync. allowed me to disconnect my account. I didn't tick/check the "clear data" checkbox. Then just logged in with the other gmail account. Asked me if it's the same user, I confirmed... and that's it!

Answer (score 23):

An old question but the current answer is out of date and I stumbled across this on my quest today (would simply comment this if I had the available rep).

Now the process is:

1. go to Menu (the 3 line/hamburger sybol in the top right) and click 'settings'
2. Select the 'disconnect' button which is one of the first buttons at the top of the main section of the settings page you just opened.  Confirm you want to leave your data on the PC (do NOT select to clear bookmarks/history etc..)
3. Close settings tab and sign-in using the man icon in the title bar.  This will prompt you that another user was previously signed in on this machine and you can either clear their data, or you can 'sign in anyway' and merge the data.  The latter is of course the one we want here.

Hey presto - job complete!

Comment: Same answer as @Chowie

Comment: This worked on the latest chrome 50, even passwords synced.

Comment: still worked with chrome 55

Comment: No longer works with Chrome 56. There is no longer an option to keep the data: Disconnecting your@email.com will clear your history, bookmarks, settings and other Chrome data stored on this device. Data stored in your Google Account will not be cleared and can be managed on Google Dashboard.

Comment: Thanks, really simple and still worked perfectly on Chrome 60

Comment: As of Chrome 65, the wording is a little different, step 2 is the "Sign Out"  button at the top, and the rest of it works. As an additional note, if the account that is being signed out of, is a "G Suite" work account, then the only option is to wipe the data from the computer.

Comment: @BeowulfNode42 Odd, I just migrated from a G Suite account to a standard Google account only last week and it let me keep my profile data on the computer. I suspect it might be down to an administrator setting somewhere within G Suite.

Comment: Working on Chrome 90.0.4430.93. 1) click the account icon at the top right side of title bar. Click "Sync is on", which will take you to chrome://settings/syncSetup. Click "Turn off" syncing. It will give you option of deleting all saved data (don't select that, obviously). Click turn off syncing. Then sign in with your new account and it will ask you whether or not to import all the data from the previous account.

Comment: sign out of your profile (turn off syncing in order to sign out). make sure new account doesn't have profile yet, delete if there is one. click turn on syncing and sign in with the new account. select the option to keep existing data.

Answer (score 3):

Hi I managed to sync my old google account with my new google account on the latest chrome and on windows 10 :)

Its as simple as what Paul did on his android.

Steps:

1. Sign out of your old google account (do not delete all history and data).
2. Sign in to your new google account immediately and it will prompt you whether to retain all data of your old account.
3. Click merge and its done.

Sorry for the non-technical terms used as I'm not a computer guy. Just trying to be helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to move my saved passwords to my new Google account with the help of this site: https://www.webnots.com/how-to-import-and-export-passwords-in-chrome/

The steps are:

1. In old account, go to chrome://settings/passwords and export the passwords by clicking the 3 vertical dots, export password csv file
2. In new account, go to chrome://flags and enable the "Import passwords" option
3. In new account, go to chrome://settings/passwords and import the password csv file.

Comment: As of January 2020, this doesn't work anymore. There is no _"import passwords"_ option in `chrome://flags`

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to figure out a way to do this on Chrome 60 on a Windows 10 machine.  However, I found a way to do it using Chrome on my Android device.  I am running Chrome 59 on a Samsung Galaxy S7 with Android 7.0.  I had both google accounts attached to the phone.  I'm not sure if it matters, but the new account was set up as the first google account on the phone.  In Chrome on my Android device, I signed into my old google account.  I then signed out of Chrome, and signed back in using my new google account.  It allowed me to merge all of my synced data.  I then logged into Chrome on my Windows machine using the new google account, and all of my chrome data from the old google account showed up.