# Transfer settings of chrome from one account to other account

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, google-chrome-extensions

I currently have the settings of chrome linked with a gmail office account (Gmail for work). Company has decided to change the MX records. So the account will get suspended. But I want to transfer all the settings (bookmarks, history, passwords)

I saw a similar [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/613469/how-can-i-transfer-google-chromes-data-and-settings-to-another-google-account)

But the problem of mine is when I try disconnect the account, it prompts me to remove the settings too. (couldn't see the checkbox to protect the data)

Instead of this:

[image]

I see this:

[image]

How to take backup of the current settings?

Comment: [How to Migrate Your Google Account to a New One](http://www.howtogeek.com/148036/how-to-migrate-your-google-account-to-a-new-one/).

Comment: [New Chrome profile: how can I migrate all browser data from one profile to another?](http://superuser.com/q/881654)